# Is there a simple way to get Result<&T, E> from Result<T, E>?

Tags: rust, rust-result

`Result<T, E>.as_ref()` will convert it to `Result<&T, &E>`, but the expected result is `Result<&T, E>`.

Comment: Do you have an owned `Result` or a borrowed?

Comment: @PitaJ No, that will complain that you are returning a reference to a function argument. You probably need to go the other direction -> `.as_ref().map_err(|&e| e)` assuming `E: Copy`. Or this might be better handled by good ol' `match`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman owned!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to place conversion in a function, the function will have to take the Result by reference. This is because, in order to use `&T` in the result type, there must be a reference in at least one of the arguments (so that the returned reference can have a lifetime). This will pose the problem in the `Err` case in which you'd ideally want to consume the original Result, but aren't allowed to do so because you get it by reference. If you can get away with requiring `E: Clone`, then this will work:

```
pub fn convert_and_return<T, E: Clone>(r: &Result<T, E>) -> Result<&T, E> {
    match r {
        Ok(t) => Ok(t),
        Err(e) => Err(e.clone()),
    }
}
```

Another possibility is to require `E` to implement `Default`, in which case you could extract the `Err(e)` from the original `Result` and leave the default in its place:

```
pub fn convert_and_return<T, E: Default>(r: &mut Result<T, E>) -> Result<&T, E> {
    match r {
        Ok(t) => Ok(t),
        Err(e) => Err(std::mem::take(e)),
    }
}
```

If you don't need to extract conversion in a function, but just want to transform the Result in-place, then you don't need to require any traits of `E`. You can either consume the result or not depending on a condition, and borrow checker will allow it. The code is then as simple as:

```
pub fn convert_and_use<T, E>(r: Result<T, E>) {
    let _r: Result<&T, E> = match r {
        Ok(ref v) => Ok(v),
        Err(e) => Err(e),
    };
    // use it here...
}
```

Comment: I thought there was a very simple function like as_ref or something like that. Thanks!